# PHP get a html list with categories with SELF JOIN sql

Tags: php, sql

Hi for school we have to make a website and we have to use a category with a self join
I want it future proof so i can add more categories in the future.

```php
function getCategories(){
    global $Conection;

    $sql = $Conection->query("SELECT * FROM Categorie r1  left JOIN dbo.Categorie r2 ON r1.Id= r2.Parent");

    $data = $sql->fetchAll();

    return $data;
}
```

```php
$categorieList= getCategories();
function renderCategories()
{
    global $categorieList;
    foreach ($categorieList as $categorie) {
       var_dump($categorie);'
// here code for a ul
    }

}
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE Categories
(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(100) NULL,
    Parent int NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Categories PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: This should work with any number of categories, why isn't it future-proof?

Comment: How you can turn this to a HTML list

Comment: `echo "<li>{$categorie['Name']} - {$category['Parent']}</li>";`

Comment: You shouldn't use `SELECT *` when you do a self-join. You'll get each column twice, but they'll have the same names, so only one of them will be in `$categorie`. You should use something like `SELECT r1.Name AS parent_name, r2.Name AS child_name, ...` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33531324/mysql-join-tables-with-duplicate-column-names

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CategoryTree#/media/File:CategoryTreeExample.png more like this