# how can i make a view using the foreign key that is applies in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, view, create-view

I am still a beginner and i searched in google ,read w3schools and couldn't get how to do it the following thing.

i want to create view from the info in cases field

[image: these are the tables i want to add info from]
AS you saw these are the info inside the tables (names,depart,idcards)

[image: the main table]

this the table i want to get the data from i made all the column start with id_* as foreign key for the PK in the previous tables

note:id_case is the PK of the table, id_dep is for department,id name is for name,id_complaint

Comment: To create a view, just write a `SELECT` query that returns the result you want, and put `CREATE VIEW viewname` before that.

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want this view to do. How are these tables related? You mention the `cases` column, but I don't see that column in any of the tables.

Comment: @Barmar i want to create a view so that all the info get in one place the cases field isn't a column it is a table which i named the main table

Comment: Please dont post text info as images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a bunch of joins:

```
CREATE VIEW viewname AS
SELECT *
FROM cases AS c
JOIN names AS n ON c.id_name = n.id
JOIN depart AS d ON c.id_dep = d.id
JOIN complaint AS cm ON c.id_complaint = cm.id
...
```

Note that if there are any column names that are the same among any of the tables, you'll need to list them explicitly in the `SELECT` list and assign distinct aliases to them. See [MySQL JOIN tables with duplicate column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33531324/mysql-join-tables-with-duplicate-column-names)

Comment: thanks ,thanks,thanks a lot i got what i want and more i liked your example it explained a lot .  : )